# Running MPI in a cluster of hosts of different platforms

Tags: c++, multiprocessing, mpi

I am new to MPI. I just read and completed the tutorial on [mpitutorial](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/running-an-mpi-cluster-within-a-lan/). Everything works fine. But I had some difficulties when I tried to put things a step further. I want to build a mini "donate your CPU time" application.

According to the tutorial, I need to specify the target hosts before running the program. How can I do it dynamically? For example, I set up a server. Every client can run a program(provided by me) and then the client do a handshake with the server and the server will assign jobs to the client dynamically. Could this be done using Open MPI or mpich2? Or, would it be better if I build my own network application and communication protocol.

Comment: There are some facilities for dynamic process communication, but **MPI is not the right tool for your job**.

Comment: So, are there any suggestions?

Comment: Consider boost::asio?